# how to change/save a value inside a .then function or query

Tags: angular, typescript

when entering a query, which gives true/false, cannot save a true/false value to a global variable

i have research/investigate the callback function but in any example provide, the functions are separated and seems to work independently of themselves

```
//outside variable
 public registro:any;

public existe(){
//making the consult
this.db.collection(this.year).doc(this.mesActual).collection(this.semana).doc(this.user.displayName).collection(this.diaMo).where("semana","==", this.semaMo).get()
        .then(doc => {
          if(doc.empty){
            // no data found!
            this.registro=false;   //<== happends to be undefined
          }
          else{
            // data found!
            this.registro=true;    //<== so as here, undefined
          }
        })
}
```

variable registro always "undefined"

Comment: What happens if you remove `this.` from `this.registro` and just say `registro=true`.  I don't know typescript, but typically `this.` refers to a instance variable.  Here `registro` appears to be a public external reference.

Comment: this.  points to the variable, if i get rid of it will  not find it. And probably might be a stupid question, but i guess thats how everyone learns.... asking. thanks everyone

Comment: Can you please show more of your program?  It would be good to see your `class` definitiion.

Comment: Also, can you show the actual error message that you are receiving?  It's unclear from your question where the variable `registro` shows up as `undefined`.

Answer (score -1):

You have a scoping issue. Perhaps simplifying would be best for you:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.registro = this.db.collection...get()
        .then(doc => {
          if(doc.empty){
            return false;   //<== happends to be undefined
          }
          else{
            return true;    //<== so as here, undefined
          }
        })
    }
}
```

Also, I voted you up.

Comment: still undefined. i try to place it in a const value = this.db.collection.....
and throws undefined

Comment: If you log `doc` what is it? Perhaps the query is bad? Also, why are you using .then over Observable methods?

Comment: i got an entire part of the consult (array probably) with that .empty part as true or false in case the data exists in firebase.
im using the .then so i cant lose that part and make the if condition.
is there other way to implement this?

Comment: what im looking for is to go and check if there is some data. depending of that, retrieve a false/true variable